# pandas.DataFrame corrwith() method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I recently start working with `pandas`. Can anyone explain me difference in behaviour of function `.corrwith()` with `Series` and `DataFrame`?

Suppose i have one `DataFrame`:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[-1,-2,-3], 'c':[10, -10, 10]})
```

And i want calculate correlation between features 'a' and all other features.
I can do it in the following way:

```
frame.drop(labels='a', axis=1).corrwith(frame['a'])
```

And result will be:

```
b   -1.0
c    0.0
```

But very similar code:

```
frame.drop(labels='a', axis=1).corrwith(frame[['a']])
```

Generate absolutely different and unacceptable table:

```
a   NaN
b   NaN
c   NaN
```

So, my question is: why in case of `DataFrame` as second argument we get such strange output?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### What I think you're looking for:

Let's say your frame is:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 6), columns=['cost', 'amount', 'day', 'month', 'is_sale', 'hour'])
```

You want the `'cost'` and `'amount'` columns to be correlated with all other columns in every combination.

```
focus_cols = ['cost', 'amount']
frame.corr().filter(focus_cols).drop(focus_cols)
```

[image]

#### Answering what you asked:

> Compute pairwise
>   correlation between rows or columns of two DataFrame objects.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **other** : DataFrame
>
> axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’},
>
> default 0 0 or ‘index’ to compute column-wise, 1 or ‘columns’ for row-wise drop : boolean, default False Drop missing indices from
>   result, default returns union of all Returns:  correls : Series

`corrwith` is behaving similarly to `add`, `sub`, `mul`, `div` in that it expects to find a `DataFrame` or a `Series` being passed in `other` despite the documentation saying just `DataFrame`.

When `other` is a `Series` it broadcast that series and matches along the axis specified by `axis`, default is 0.  This is why the following worked:

```
frame.drop(labels='a', axis=1).corrwith(frame.a)

b   -1.0
c    0.0
dtype: float64
```

When `other` is a `DataFrame` it will match the axis specified by `axis` and correlate each pair identified by the other axis.  If we did:

```
frame.drop('a', axis=1).corrwith(frame.drop('b', axis=1))

a    NaN
b    NaN
c    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Only `c` was in common and only `c` had its correlation calculated.

In the case you specified:

```
frame.drop(labels='a', axis=1).corrwith(frame[['a']])
```

`frame[['a']]` is a `DataFrame` because of the `[['a']]` and now plays by the `DataFrame` rules in which its columns must match up with what its being correlated with.  But you explicitly drop `a` from the first frame then correlate with a `DataFrame` with nothing but `a`.  The result is `NaN` for every column.

Comment: Okay, but what if i have data about some store. And now i want calculate correlation between `cost`,`amount` and other features from my database (features like `day`, `month`, `is_sale`, `hour` etc). Unfortunally, we can't code this like `frame[['cost', 'amount']].corrwith(frame.drop(labels=['cost', 'amount'], axis=1))`. So, how can i do this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to correlate every column from one dataframe with every column in another dataframe. `frame[['cost', 'amount']]` has 2 columns and say `frame.drop(labels=['cost', 'amount'], axis=1)` has 4 columns, your looking for 2 x 4 matrix of correlations.  Am I right?  If so, you need to ask another question.  In this question, you asked to understand the behavior you were observing.  It's been explained by MaxU and myself.  In so explaining, you may have realized that `corrwith` might not be the thing your looking for because it won't give you that 2 x 4 correlation matrix.

Comment: No, i want to understand behaviour of this function. And i want understand the reason of such behavior. May be my last comment not quite correct, but i think, that pairwise correlation will be more useful that current behaviour. And more logical, because function with `Series` works exactly in this way: calculate pairwise correlation.

Comment: `pairwise` means that if I have 2 lists, I will take the first with the first, the second with the second and so on.  Think of python's `zip`.  In this context, `corrwith` is doing the same thing with the exception that its letting the `columns` guide how to do the pairing.  An exception is made when a `Series` is passed and it broadcasts the `Series` across all columns.  This is for convenience and is technically inconsistent with the documentation.  However, its behavior seems the obvious choice and is convenient.  You're expecting the exception to now be the rule when it isn't.

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin, i think you should really ask another question and give a little bit more details about what do you want to achieve (as  piRSquared has already proposed) - i have a feeling that you are doing something similar to [feature selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_selection), but it's just a wild guess...

Comment: @MaxU No, i really thought that `corrwith()` should calculate all element to element correlations. But @piRSquared explain my mistakes.

Answer (score 7):

corrwith defined as `DataFrame.corrwith(other, axis=0, drop=False)`, so the `axis=0` per default - i.e. `Compute pairwise correlation between columns of two **DataFrame** objects`

So the column names / labels must be the same in both DFs:

```
In [134]: frame.drop(labels='a', axis=1).corrwith(frame[['a']].rename(columns={'a':'b'}))
Out[134]:
b   -1.0
c    NaN
dtype: float64
```

`NaN`- means (in this case) there is nothing to compare / correlate with, because there is NO column named `c` in `other` DF

if you pass a series as `other` it will be translated (from the [link](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/7dd4091458d9117e57d2ad9ce3126855bd00108c/pandas/core/frame.py#L4753), you've posted in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422001/pandas-dataframe-corrwith-method#comment64250459_38422030)) into:

```
In [142]: frame.drop(labels='a', axis=1).apply(frame.a.corr)
Out[142]:
b   -1.0
c    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: In documentation - yes. But in code on GitHub exist special case for `Series`: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/7dd4091458d9117e57d2ad9ce3126855bd00108c/pandas/core/frame.py#L4753. And question still opened: why in case of `DataFrame` we get such output? I thought that .corrwith() must calculate correlation between all pairs from self's and other's frames columns. But in the example result always Nan.

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin, i've updated my answer - please check

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxFeB.png)

A simple output

Answer (score 0):

Sorry a bit late.. 
There is no way of corwith of series while panda dataframe could only be analyzed with having same columnz

like

x = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8.2]).reshape(-1, 1)

y = np.array([2.3, 3.11, .5, 7, 10, 11, 12]).reshape(-1, 1)

a = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['aa'])
b = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['aa'])

a.corrwith(b)