# correlation matrix of one dataframe with another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I was reading through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422001/pandas-dataframe-corrwith-method).  Then question came up on how to calculate the correlations of all columns from one dataframe with all columns from the other dataframe.  Since it seemed this question wasn't going to get answered, I wanted to ask it as I need something just like that.

So say I have dataframes `A` and `B`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(24, 5), columns=list('abcde'))
B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(24, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
```

how do I get a dataframe that looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame([], A.columns, B.columns)

     A    B    C    D    E
a  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
b  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
c  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
d  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
e  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

But filled with the appropriate correlations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it would be:

```
pd.concat([A, B], axis=1).corr().filter(B.columns).filter(A.columns, axis=0)
```

[image]

A more efficient way would be:

```
Az = (A - A.mean())
Bz = (B - B.mean())

Az.T.dot(Bz).div(len(A)).div(Bz.std(ddof=0)).div(Az.std(ddof=0), axis=0)
```

And you'd get the same as above.

Comment: Doesn't this seem inefficient as you're calculating 100 correlations when you only need 25?  But that is a nice answer.

Comment: @Brian that is true.  I posted an alternative.

Comment: @piRSquared Actually ddof should be 0 to get the same results. It's strange though.

Comment: @ayhan whoops, that was an experiment.

Comment: Thank you @piRSquared.  I'll end up using this a lot.

Comment: Interestingly, the first line answer only works if both dataframes do not have same column names, else you receive: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.