# Correlation matrix of two Pandas dataframe, with P values

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, dataframe, correlation

I was using this function (see bottom) to calculate both Pearson and Pval starting from two dataframes, but I am not confident with Pval results: it seems that too many negative correlations are significant.

Is there a more elegant way (like one-line-code), in order to calculate Pval along with Pearson?

These two answers ([pandas.DataFrame corrwith() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422001/pandas-dataframe-corrwith-method)) and ([correlation matrix of one dataframe with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422893/correlation-matrix-of-one-dataframe-with-another)) provided elegant solutions, but P values calculation is missing.

Here is the code:

```
def pearson_cross_map(df1, df2):
    """Correlate each Mvar with each Nvar.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df1 : dataframe1
    Shape Mobs X Mvar.

    df2 : dataframe2
    Shape Nobs X Nvar.

    Returns
    -------
    DFcorr, dataframe Mvar x Nvar in which each element is a Pearson 
correlation coefficient.
    DFpval, dataframe Mvar x Nvar in which each element is a P value (one-tailed).

    """

    intersection = (df1.index & df2.index).tolist()
    df1 = df1.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) 
    df1 = df1.T[intersection].T 
    df1 = df1.loc[:, (df1 != 0).any(axis=0)].sort().sort(axis=1)    
    df2 = df2.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    df2 = df2.T[intersection].T
    df2 = df2.loc[:, (df2 != 0).any(axis=0)].sort().sort(axis=1)
    x = df1.T.values
    y = df2.T.values
    mu_x = x.mean(1)
    mu_y = y.mean(1)
    n = x.shape[1]
    s_x = x.std(1, ddof=n - 1)
    s_y = y.std(1, ddof=n - 1)
    cov = np.dot(x,y.T) - n * np.dot(mu_x[:, np.newaxis], mu_y[np.newaxis, :])
    DFcoeff = pd.DataFrame(cov / np.dot(s_x[:, np.newaxis], s_y[np.newaxis, :]))
    DFcoeff.index = df1.columns.tolist()
    DFcoeff.columns = df2.columns.tolist()
    n = len(intersection)
    r = DFcoeff
    t = r*np.sqrt((n-2)/(1-r*r))
    DFpval = pd.DataFrame(stats.t.cdf(t, n-2))
    DFpval.index = df1.columns.tolist()
    DFpval.columns = df2.columns.tolist()
    return DFcoeff, DFpval
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You require Pearson correlation testing and not just correlation calculation. Hence, use the [scipy.stats.pearsonr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) method which returns the estimated Pearson coefficient and 2-tailed pvalue.

Since the method requires a series input, consider iterating through each column of both dataframes to update pre-assigned matrices. Even cast to dataframe with needed columns and index:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5), columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5), columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'])

coeffmat = np.zeros((df1.shape[1], df2.shape[1]))
pvalmat = np.zeros((df1.shape[1], df2.shape[1]))

for i in range(df1.shape[1]):    
    for j in range(df2.shape[1]):        
        corrtest = pearsonr(df1[df1.columns[i]], df2[df2.columns[j]])  

        coeffmat[i,j] = corrtest[0]
        pvalmat[i,j] = corrtest[1]

dfcoeff = pd.DataFrame(coeffmat, columns=df2.columns, index=df1.columns)
print(dfcoeff)
#           Col1      Col2      Col3      Col4      Col5
# Col1 -0.791083  0.459101 -0.488463 -0.289265  0.494897
# Col2  0.059446 -0.395072  0.310900  0.297532  0.201669
# Col3 -0.062592  0.391469 -0.450600 -0.136554  0.299579
# Col4 -0.470203  0.797971 -0.193561 -0.338896 -0.244132
# Col5 -0.057848 -0.037053  0.042798  0.176966 -0.157344

dfpvals = pd.DataFrame(pvalmat, columns=df2.columns, index=df1.columns)
print(dfpvals)
#           Col1      Col2      Col3      Col4      Col5
# Col1  0.006421  0.181967  0.152007  0.417574  0.145871
# Col2  0.870421  0.258506  0.381919  0.403770  0.576357
# Col3  0.863615  0.263268  0.191245  0.706796  0.400385
# Col4  0.170260  0.005666  0.592096  0.338101  0.496668
# Col5  0.873881  0.919058  0.906551  0.624783  0.664206
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for :-) very elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

You could compare this with bootstrap significance (i.e. if you shuffle randomly one series, what is the probability that you will get the same or greater correlation). This is not the same thing as Pearson's p-value as the latter was derived with assumption that your data is normally distributed, so you could get somewhat different result if it is not the case.

```
bootstrapLen = 1000
leng= 10000
X, Y= [np.random.randn(leng) for _ in [1,2]]
correlation = np.correlate(X,Y)/leng

bootstrap = [ abs(np.correlate(X,Y[np.random.permutation(leng)])/leng) for _ in range(bootstrapLen)]
bootstrap = np.sort(np.ravel(bootstrap))
significance = np.searchsorted(bootstrap, abs(correlation)) / bootstrapLen

print("correlation is {} with significance {}".format(correlation,significance))
```