# Finding the correlation between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

```
 TeamA   TeamB   TeamC
 12        17        19
 13        20        21
 14        21        26
 15        22        15

    
    difference = numpy.abs(data['TeamA'] - data['TeamB'])
    teamC = data['TeamC']
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(difference)
    df1.columns = ['diff']
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(teamC)
    correlation = df1.corrwith(df2,axis=0)
```

I am looking to return the correlation between (the absolute points difference between team A and Team B) and the number of points of team C. However, my code is not returning any number. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

pandas is expecting a series inside the corrwith instead of a dataframe (despite what the documentations say).

This makes sense because just passing a dataframe does not really help since you do not know which columns to use for generating correlation score

You should instead be doing:

```
df1.corrwith(df2["TeamC"])
```

OUT

```
diff    0.18221
dtype: float64
```

This answer is just an extension of this thread:

[pandas.DataFrame corrwith() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422001/pandas-dataframe-corrwith-method)